# html horizontal two-element lists

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list of names that I'm displaying in one cell of a table with a space between each.  For formatting reasons I want to avoid putting each in its own table cell.  I now want to put a small avatar or photo above each name. I can obviously do one person as `<img src="photo.gif"><br>name...`  but using 
 or

obviously creates a vertical not horizontal list.  I can no longer use spaces obviously.

Is there any horizontal version of a `<br>` tag that I could use to space out the people?

Alternatively, is there a way to do this with css?  I found some references to placing images side by side using float left, however, the text is not in a tag.  Using multiple span tags does not seem so appealing.  Here is img code I found.

```
.left{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: @Ozzy: please [remove thanks and greetings when editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following CSS:

```
.horizontalList li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

You can make an element which usually displays as a block i.e. `<LI>` , `<DIV>` , etc to display inline. The margins are just added to give a little space between each element.

So for example,

```
<UL class="horizontalList">
    <LI><img src="img1.png"/>Person 1</LI>
    <LI><img src="img2.png"/>Person 2</LI>
    <LI><img src="img3.png"/>Person 3</LI>
    <LI><img src="img4.png"/>Person 4</LI>
</UL>
```

Just as well, you can alter the style of the images to display as a block rather than inline, so you can add this CSS to do that:

```
.horizontalList img {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```